# Split-normal distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, gaussian

What's the best way to compute a split-normal distribution given a mean value with an upper and lower error?

So far I have:

```
from random import choice, gauss
def random_split_normal(mu: float, upper_sigma: float, lower_sigma:int) -> float:
    return abs(gauss(0.0, 1.0)) * choice([upper_sigma, -lower_sigma]) + mu
```

which I call lots of times to generate an array:

```
random_array = []
for _ in range(1000):
    random_array.append(random_split_normal(1.0, 2.0, 1.0))
```

which yields the following result when making a histogram of `random_array`:

[image]

I'm wondering if randomly using either `upper_sigma` or `lower_sigma` is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is mathematically equivalent, but less efficient since you're unnecessarily applying abs() and choice() where you can just look at the gauss()'s sign.

This should be close to the definition. I've also reoredred the sigmas to coincide with our usual numberline orientation (negative infinity on the left)

```
def random_split_normal(mu: float, lower_sigma: float, upper_sigma: float) -> float:
    z = gauss(0, 1)
    return mu + z * (lower_sigma if z < 0 else upper_sigma)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like to reverse order `sigma` values, as typically I say "answer is x plus and minus y". But that's just me!

Comment: That's reasonable. Thank you for the edit recommendations!

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis I don't think normal(0, 1) works, so I changed it back. Also removed some duplication in the return.

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis please consider accepting this answer if you found it helpful :)